# Replace values from db in an array

Tags: javascript

I have an array, where the values are fetched from db lets say,

```
var ndp_static_hw = new Array("AB34AB3472AB","AB2265445588");
```

I need to colonize the values (ex: AB:34:AB:34:72:AB) and have it in seperate array say, `ndp_static_hw_colonized`.

how would we do this?

Comment: Give us something you already tried.

Comment: Please share the expected output format based on your given input along with your attempt.

Comment: Expected output is, var ndp_static_hw_colonized= new Array("AB:34:AB:34:72:AB","AB:22:65:44:55:88");

Answer (score 0):

```
 const colonized = array.map(str => str.split("").map((el, i) => i%2 && i != str.length - 1 ? (el + ":") : el).join(""));
```

Comment: I love one liners, but damn this makes my brain hurt :)

Comment: @Derpanel i hope so :) i put the same effort into explaining and optimizing as the OP ...

Answer (score 0):

It looks that you are still at the beginning of array and string manipulation.

In the following code, I go through the array and, in each iteration, modify the string the way you want.

```
var myArray= new Array("AB34AB3472AB","AB2265445588");
var newArray = [];

myArray.forEach(function(item) {   


    colItem = '';
    for (var i=0; i<item.length; i = i + 2)
        colItem = colItem + item.charAt(i) + item.charAt(i + 1) + ':';

    newArray.push(colItem);  



})
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on

> I need to colonize the values (ex: AB:34:AB:34:72:AB) and have it in seperate array say, ndp_static_hw_colonized.

Use `map`, `match` and `join`

```
["AB34AB3472AB","AB2265445588"].map( c => c.match(/.{1,2}/g).join( ":" ) )
```

This produces output as

> ["AB:34:AB:34:72:AB", "AB:22:65:44:55:88"]

**Demo**

```js
var input = ["AB34AB3472AB","AB2265445588"];
var output = input.map( c => c.match(/.{1,2}/g).join( ":" ) );
console.log(output);
```

If there could be some empty values as well, such as

```
var ndp_static_hw = new Array("AB34AB3472AB","AB2265445588", "" );
```

Then filter out such values before applying `map`

```
ndp_static_hw.filter( s => String(s).length > 0 )
             .map( c => c.match(/.{1,2}/g).join( ":" ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var ndp_static_hw = new Array("AB34AB3472AB","AB2265445588");
var result = ndp_static_hw.map(function(s){ return s.match(/\S{2}/g).join(":");});
console.log(result);
```